# Adding new service type in Cloudera Manager

Tags: cloudera, cloudera-manager

I'm following [official](https://docs.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/latest/topics/cm_mc_add_service.html) docs to add service to a cluster in Cloudera Manager.

However it's custom service developed in-house and there's no service type shown.

How to add new service type in Cloudera Manager?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to deploy CSD of new service.

Then, it's possible to select new service type and add new service of this type.